# Align UIVIew starting from middle screen

Tags: ios, uiview

I would like to do UIViews, UILabels, etc. aligned starting from middle screen using InterfaceBuilder like this...

Blue - Middle Screen

Red - Controls aligned from middle towards screen border.

[image]

What could be the constraint(S) needed??

Comment: Do you want to do this in IB or in code? Do you need the views to maintain that arrangement on rotation?

Comment: Did you see my additional question in my comment?

Comment: Sorry.. No need, my app will only work on landscape mode, so no rotation needed, but need to adjust either retina/noretina screens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give that top view a constraint to the left edge of the screen with a value that's half the width of the screen. You can then select all the views and choose "Leading Edges" under the "Add New Alignment Constraints" section of the "Align"  button at the bottom right side of the canvas.

Comment: I'm currently doing that thing, just the way you proposed, with a combination of @John Riselvato's answer

Comment: @FredericYesidPeñaSánchez, you really shouldn't combine constraints with code that sets frames. When you use constraints, you shouldn't explicitly set any frames -- do everything with constraints.

Comment: don't worry, i'm using the calculation but not setting the frame. Basically link an IBOutlet of the top view constraint and adjust it's "constant" property accordingly.

Comment: Can IB implement this, didn't find a way.

Answer (score 1):

```
float middle = self.view.bounds.size.width/2;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(middle, 0.0 + (75.0 * i),  100.0, 50.)];
     [self.view addSubview:view];
}
```

Pretty simple, just set the x location to the middle of the screen in the CGRect

Comment: There is some way of doing this on IB?

Answer (score 1):

You're basically looking for the leading edge of each child to be half the width of the parent.

According to the docs, `constraintWithItem:...` uses the formula `attribute1 == multiplier × attribute2 + constant`, so for each child view, you could do this with a constraint:

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:view.superview
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth 
                            multiplier:0.5
                              constant:0]
```

Rather than doing this once for each child, you could create a subview to host all the children with one constraint.

As far as Interface builder goes, there's nothing in Xcode 5.**0** that would allow you do do this but you should check the developer program for a beta.

Comment: In fact there is a mixed solution that works very well, see the two answers before yours... Also adding a subview to hold the other views doesn't seem comfortable for me.